# Transform dates Error: The conditional operation failed

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

The *Data Flow Task* seems to fail at the *Transform dates* task with the below error message.

> [Transform dates [385]] Error: The conditional operation failed.
>   [Transform dates [385]] Error: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Transform dates" failed
>   because error code 0xC0049063 occurred, and the error row disposition
>   on "Transform dates.Outputs[Derived Column
>   Output].Columns[DerivedCallStartTest]" specifies failure on error. An
>   error occurred on the specified object of the specified component. 
>   There may be error messages posted before this with more information
>   about the failure.
>
> ```
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Transform dates" (385) failed
> ```
>
> with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Derived Column
>   Input" (386). The identified component returned an error from the
>   ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the
>   error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running. 
>   There may be error messages posted before this with more information
>   about the failure.

The Transform dates is a DerivedColumn task which has the below code to create two new columns.

```
(CallStart == "BLANK") ? NULL(DT_DBTIMESTAMP) : (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)CallStart
(Callend == "BLANK") ? NULL(DT_DBTIMESTAMP) : (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)Callend
```

I also enabled the dataviewer to check what data was being passed to the task image attached for reference.

Am I missing something or what could be the reason for failure, any help or lead would be great.

[image]

Comment: try `(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)NULL` instead of `NULL(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)`. meanwhile give the data type of your column too

Comment: @PrabhatG I tried to configure the error output from the Tranfoem Dates to a flatfile and found a strange thing that I didnt notice before. The error thrown is because of the third line in the Dataviewer, it should actually pick only the first two. And for the datatypes of the columns in the Transform Dates is DT_DBTIMESTAMP

Comment: @PrabhatG could you let me know how to skip the TTRAILER record so that its not picked up in the Header File task itself

Comment: inbetween lines can only be skipped if you use `conditional split transformation`. Put up the data present in header file. I'll try to replicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made use of a FileConnection Manager and created a new file with the contents of the input file and skipped the Trailer record from being copied over to this file.
Finally started reading through the newly created file and was able to pass the task successfully.